# Proving $||A^{-1} v || \geq ||A^{-1} u ||$ implies $||v|| \geq ||u||$.

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, matrix-norms

I hope to show that $||A^{-1} v || \geq ||A^{-1} u || \implies ||v|| \geq ||u||$ .

$A$ is a positive definite matrix of size $n \times n$ and $v, u$ is a vector of size $n \times 1$.

$||\cdot||$ can be any norm (e.g., 1-norm or 2-norm). That is, if $||\cdot||$ should be 1-norm to satisfy the equation, it is ok, and I would like to know that condition.

How can I prove this?
If I can't, which conditions are additionally needed?
Or, I wonder if this is absolutely impossible.

I would really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I don't think this can work with just any norm.  As a counter-example, take $A = \begin{pmatrix} .01 & 0\\0 & .01\end{pmatrix}$, $u = (0.1, 0.1)^T$, $v = (1, 1)^T$, and use the cut-off norm,  $d(x, y) = \min(\|x - y\|, 1)$.

Comment: Oh, my word could be misleading. I wanted to say that norm is not specified. So, for example, if only 1-norm can satisfy the equation, it doesn't matter. I'll modify the writing. Thank you for comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Let $A^{-1}v = \lambda v$ and $A^{-1}u = \mu u$. Then what you are trying to prove is $\lambda \lVert v \rVert \geq \mu \lVert u \rVert$ implies $\lVert v \rVert \geq \lVert u \rVert$, which is obviously not true for any norm.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation!